# Creating a default initialized list of size n in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

Is there a Elixir or Erlang function that creates a list of size n, default initialized with a given value?

Examples of the functionality in other languages:

```
# Python
l = [0] * 5

# Ruby
l = Array.new(5, 0)

# => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Remember that Elixir has immutable data structures as well as Erlang and Lists are not Arrays!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's [`List.duplicate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#duplicate/2):

```
iex(1)> List.duplicate(:foo, 3)
[:foo, :foo, :foo]
```

If instead of a static value you want to initialise the list with results of some computation you can always use for comprehensions:

```
iex(2)> for _i <- 1..3, do: :erlang.timestamp()
[{1484, 271802, 581891}, {1484, 271802, 581900}, {1484, 271802, 581906}]
```